# dash_styles in Highcharts

Tags: r, highcharts, linechart, r-highcharter

I am trying to change the dashStyle of a Line chart in Highcharts.

I referred to [RDocumentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highcharter/highcharter.pdf) , page 7, There is no example of it anywhere. All it says is use `dash_styles()`

Then i checked [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dashStyle) and tried, but it is not resulting in what i need.

```
library(highcharter)
  highchart() %>% 
    hc_title(text = title) %>% 
    hc_xAxis(categories = batchno) %>% 
    hc_add_series(name = "Mixer A", data = A,
                  color = "hotpink", pointWidth = 20, type = "line",
                 dash_styles(style = "LongDot")) %>% 
    hc_add_series(name = "Mixer B" , data = B,
                  color =  "slateblue", pointWidth = 20,type = "line") %>%

    hc_chart(type = "column") %>% 

    hc_yAxis(
      list(lineWidth = 3, lineColor='seashell', title=list(text= "text"),max= 10)) %>% hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE, shared =  TRUE)
}
```

How do i use this dash_style ?

Comment: Please share reproducible example!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dash_styles` is only a helper function show what types of dash you can use.

Check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-dashstyle/). You'll see you need only give the name of the type of dash:

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(data = rnorm(5), dashStyle = "longdash") %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = rnorm(5), dashStyle = "DashDot")
```

[image]